# how to create a pop up window #2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

is there a way to create a pop-up window in a VB.Net application, specifically when a button has been clicked?

I'm designing a little help section on a web application I'm working on, and I wanted to have a variety of written steps followed by some sort of "Click here for an example" button that brings up a new window (not a new page, just a new window). The window would simply contain an image control displaying a picture that describes the written steps.

The best example I can come up with is [here on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005C2P6N2) when ordering a clothing item such as a pair of shoes. When the user clicks the "Sizing Info" link button, a pop-up window appears with information to help you order the correct size.

So is there a way to create a pop up like that in VB.Net?

Comment: Is this for a web application? Or a traditional desktop application?

Comment: It's for a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vb.net not, websites are handled differently. For displaying a popup using asp.net you need a client-side language, like javascript.

For instance this nice jquery script http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Your vb.net can't open dialogs on client-side. If you need to get/send some information from the server, simply use webservices to send/fetch the information using ajax.

Comment: Okay, that's kind of what I thought based on some other research I did. Thanks for answering!